# Sort Data Case-Insensitively in Oracle SQL with Uppercase Letters First

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm working on an Oracle SQL query, and I'm trying to sort my data in a specific way.

I want the data to be sorted case-insensitive, but with uppercase letters appearing before lowercase letters.

For example, I want "Apple" to come before "apple"

Here's an example of the wanted sorting order:

```
Apple
apple
Banana
banana
Bananb
Grape
orange
Pineapple
```

this is my query:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM your_table
ORDER BY NLSSORT(column_name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI');
```

Comment: How is this "Java"?

Comment: using PreparedStatement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to sort by the same column twice; first time force e.g. *lowercase* (so that all apples go before all bananas before all grapes ...), and then apply `NLS_SORT`:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select
  3     'banana'    from dual union all select
  4     'apple'     from dual union all select
  5     'Apple'     from dual union all select
  6     'Banana'    from dual union all select
  7     'Grape'     from dual union all select
  8     'orange'    from dual union all select
  9     'Bananb'    from dual union all select
 10     'Pineapple' from dual
 11    )
```

Query:

```
 12  select * from test
 13  order by lower(col), nlssort(col, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY');

COL
---------
Apple
apple
Banana
banana
Bananb
Grape
orange
Pineapple

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort once case insensitively and then sort case sensitively:

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY LOWER(column_name), column_name;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY 
       NLSSORT(column_name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'),
       NLSSORT(column_name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (column_name) AS
SELECT 'Apple'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'apple'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Banana'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bananb'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grape'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'orange'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pineapple' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| COLUMN_NAME |
| --- |
| Apple |
| apple |
| Banana |
| banana |
| Bananb |
| Grape |
| orange |
| Pineapple |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qSVDY5wA)